# Como imprimir um valor decimal com virgula ex: 75,0 ficaria 7,5?

Tags: c#, formatação

```
using System; 

class teste {

    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        float nota1, nota2, MEDIA;
        med1;
        nota1=float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        nota2=float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        MEDIA=((nota2+nota1)/2);

        string med1 = MEDIA.ToString("0.00"); //EU GOSTARIA DE IMPRIMIR O VALOR COMO EX: 7.5 E NÃO 75,0
        Console.WriteLine(media1);  
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *"EU GOSTARIA DE IMPRIMIR O VALOR COMO EX: 7.5"* se quer o formato com ponto faça só `.ToString()`

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Modificar saída de valor de nota](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/492958/modificar-sa%c3%adda-de-valor-de-nota)

Comment: Quais são os valores passados para nota1 e nota2? Pq sendo passados os valores corretos vc não precisa fazer nada.

Comment: "*75,0 ficaria 7,5*" - isso está confuso, pois `75,0` é **setenta e cinco**, e `7,5` é **sete e meio**, e na pergunta ainda é dito "*7.5 E NÃO 75,0*" (ou seja, além de ter mudado o valor, também mudou o ponto em vez da vírgula). O seu problema é que o valor está dando errado, é somente formatação (número de casas decimais, separador decimal, etc), ou ambos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer a formatação do valor da sua variável `MEDIA` com [string.Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0):

```
string med1 = string.Format("{0:0.0}", MEDIA);
```

O resultado obtido seria (baseado no comentário do código que está na pergunta):

```
7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Converta o valor numérico em sua representação string equivalente usando um formato especificado com o método [`Single.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Single_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) onde:

- `format` é uma [String de formato numérico padrão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString) usada para formatar tipos numéricos comuns no caso utilizando [especificador de formato de ponto fixo `"F"`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier).
- `provider` é um [NumberFormatInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=net-5.0) que fornece informações específicas para formatar e analisar valores numéricos, onde os campos [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator) e [`NumberDecimalDigits`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits) serão configurados respectivamente com `"."` e `1` para definir a string que separa os dígitos integrais dos decimais e define quantidade de dígitos decimais.

---

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        float nota1, nota2, MEDIA;
        nota1=float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        nota2=float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        MEDIA=(nota2+nota1)/2;

        Console.WriteLine(MEDIA.ToString("F", new NumberFormatInfo{
                NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
                NumberDecimalDigits = 1
        }));  
    }
}
```

[Teste o código.](https://ideone.com/oLUBE4)